# return 'sockets, length, add, del' when get room's client list in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Now I'm working on socket.io 1.7.3 and trying to get clients list in a room.

Referring some codes, I wrote the code below,

```
var clientlist = getAllRoomMembers('room0');

console.log('clientlist:'+clientlist);

function getAllRoomMembers(room, _nsp) {
    var roomMembers = [];
    var nsp = (typeof _nsp !== 'string') ? '/' : _nsp;

    for( var member in io.of('/').adapter.rooms[room] ) {
        roomMembers.push(member);
    }

    return roomMembers;
}
```

But when clients joined room, console returns below,

```
clientlist:sockets,length,add,del
```

Do you have any ideas why this is happened?

Thank you!

Comment: `roomMembers` will be all the enumerable properties of `io.of('/').adapter.rooms[room]` -whatever that is

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you for your reply.
So, this code, io.of('/').adapter.rooms[room] doesn't work to get client list, right?

Comment: you tell me, it's your code